# Formal criterion of availability to implement algorithm using MapReduce paradigm

Tags: mapreduce, bigdata

> Computational model supported by MapReduce is expressive enough to compute almost any function on your data.

1. If I understood correctly there are algorithms which can not be implemented using `MapReduce` paradigm. Is it correct ?
2. Are there any criteria, formal or otherwise, to discern whether an algorithm can be implemented using `MapRuduce`?